# Nitrogen dioxide fluorescence quenching and lifetime

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, photochemistry, fluorescence

Nitrogen dioxide fluorescence quenching:

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{NO2 + h\nu &->[$\varphi_\mathrm{Ia}$] NO2^{\ast}}\tag{I}\\
\ce{NO2^{\ast} &->[$k_2$] NO2 + h\nu'}\tag{II}\\
\ce{NO2^{\ast} + NO2 &->[$k_3$] 2 NO2}\tag{III}\\
\ce{NO2^{\ast} + Xe &->[$k_4$] NO2 + Xe}\tag{IV}\\
\ce{NO2^{\ast} + NO2 &->[$k_5$] 2 NO + O2}\tag{V}\\
\end{align}
$$

The fluorescence lifetime of $\ce{NO2^{\ast}}$ in the presence of all the reactions, $\tau$, measured at $\pu{298 K}$ at different concentrations (molecules per litre) of the reactants:

$$
\begin{array}{crrr}
\hline
\text{Experiment} & \tau/\pu{μs} & [\ce{Xe}]/\pu{L-1} & [\ce{NO2}]/\pu{L-1}
 \\
\hline
1 & 3.38 & \pu{1.6E19} & \pu{3.2E18} \\
2 & 1.89 & \pu{1.6E19} & \pu{6.4E18} \\
3 & 3.64 & \pu{0.8E19} & \pu{3.2E18} \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

What is the real fluorescence lifetime of $\ce{NO2^{\ast}}?$

Is this question valid? Isn't the lifetime vs the concentration of the quencher supposed to be linear?

Comment: Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown. It might also help if add some more details as to where this data is taken from: is this a textbook exercise, or an experiment conducted by you?

Comment: Thanks! it's a HW assignment by my tutor. I'm not sure if this is solvable or not.

Comment: @andselisk why did you use `\phi` instead of `\varphi`?

Comment: @Zenix No reason, both are equally usable to me. Probably an old habit to avoid `\var` prefix from using $\mathrm\LaTeX.$ If you are interested in the whole var-thing, have a look at [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304534/what-does-the-var-prefix-stand-for-in-varphi-and-varepsilon-etc). But you are right, since the source image had φ and not ɸ, I changed my edit to `\varphi`. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Given that the question was constructed by your tutor, I suspect the question is really about half-life (a clue is a halving of the concentration).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for the rate constant $1/\tau^0=k_2$. The rate equation for the $\ce{NO2^*}$ is (using $N^*$ for $\ce{[NO2^*]}$ and N for ground state NO2), $\displaystyle \frac{dN^*}{dt}=-k_2N^*$ and when quenched $\displaystyle \frac{dN^*}{dt}=-k_2N^* -N^*((k_3+k_5)N+k_4[Xe])$ which can both be integrated to give exponentials, i.e $N^*=N^*_0e^{-k_2t}$ and similarly for the other equation. Writing the rate constants as $1/\tau^0=k_2$ and $1/\tau_Q=k_2+(k_3+k_5)N+k_4[Xe]$ you can find the values after looking at the pattern of the quencher concentrations in the question.